# How to print font Libre Barcode EAN13 Text in Google Sheet

Tags: google-sheets, barcode

i am trying print barcode, in my sheet is working:

[image]

But when i trying print in my printer, show me the numbers:

[image]

Comment: Are your bar codes images? In cell or overlayed? How did you insert them? Can you share a sample spreadsheet for troubleshooting?

Comment: yes,thanks for now, follow: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1HawmM2MecczZMFRax3pqRyU5T4ss2W_R_RniuA5kK-o/edit#gid=0

Comment: I am using Libre Barcode EAN13 Text font by Google

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### You inserted your barcode as a font, this causes formatting problems when printing

As a workaround, take an approach that insert your barcode as an image instead of a font.

There are plenty third party websites that offer free bar code generation.

Try for example to insert into column B the formula
`=image("http://berrywing.com/barcode/Code128.aspx?bc=" & A2)`

This will generate an image from the barcode returned from the specified URL with the content of cell `A2`.

Comment: Ismael, note that i saw the "error" (blank result) in your sheet with the above formula.  Just change & A2 to  & VALUE(A2), and it returns a barcode correctly.  But it returns a Code 128 format barcode.  I'm not sure if that is what you want.  I don't know if there is a similar online service to return a UPC format barcode - I couldn't find one, but I'm sure there must be...

Answer (score 0):

After i search for long time, i find some solution.

i am using the following command to produce barcode EAN13:

IMAGE("https://barcode.tec-it.com/barcode.ashx?data="&G2&"&code=EAN13&dpi=360&dataseparator="

thanks for all

Answer (score 0):

Use this link to create an image. You have but to keep in mind, that the EAN13 demands exactly 12 digits (or 13 for the last digit to be the checksum), otherwise you'll get an error.

```
https://barcode.tec-it.com/barcode.ashx?code=EAN13&data=123456789012
```

to use it in sheets or excel, use this:

```
=image('https://barcode.tec-it.com/barcode.ashx?code=EAN13&data='&A2)
```